# Libvirt and bash completion on Slackware-current: why domain is not completed?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, virsh

Very strange situation on Slackware-current.
With libvirt-6.8.0 compiled by source.

Let start bash completion

```
virst st<TAB>
virsh start OK

virsh start --dom<TAB>
virsh start --domain OK

virsh start --domain <TAB>
Display all 235 possibilities? (y or n)
```

235 possibilities? I have only 15 domains configured and the 235 files are my files and dirs in home, seems bash completion cannot complete the domain list, the other commands (virsh domiflist, virsh dominfo, virsh domifaddr) works fine with tab completion. All expect domain list.
I have try removing all libvirt files, and reinstall libvirt but nothing...
what can block my domain bash completion?

I have tried to debug bash

```
set -x
```

Run command

```
virsh start --domain ce<TAB>

+ local flag_all=1 array ret a b ifaces nwfilters files
+ COMPREPLY=()
+ cur=cen
+ prev=--domain
+++ virsh -h
+++ grep '^    '
+++ cut '-d ' -f5
+++ virsh -h
+++ cut -d= -f1
+++ grep '\--'
+++ cut '-d ' -f7
++ echo '-c
-d
-e
-h
-k

-K

-l
-q
-r
-t
-v
-V

attach-device
attach-disk
...
very long list of virsh commands
cd
echo
exit
help
pwd
quit
connect' '--connect
--debug
--escape
--help
--keepalive-interval
--keepalive-count
--log
--quiet
--readonly
--timing'
+ cmds='-c
-d
-e
-h
-k

-K

-l
-q
-r
-t
-v
-V

attach-device
...
very long list of virsh commands
echo
exit
help
pwd
quit
connect --connect
--debug
--escape
--help
--keepalive-interval
--keepalive-count
--log
--quiet
--readonly
--timing'
++ virsh help
++ grep '^    '
++ cut '-d ' -f5
+ cmds_help='attach-device
attach-disk
attach-interface
autostart
blkdeviotune
blkiotune
blockcommit
...very long list of virsh commands
cd
echo
exit
help
pwd
quit
connect'
+ case "$prev" in
++ _virsh_list_domains 1
++ local flag_all=1 flags
++ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
++ flags=--all
++ virsh -q list --all
++ cut '-d ' -f7
++ awk '{print $1}'
+ doms=
+ COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$doms" -- "$cur"))
++ compgen -W '' -- cen
+ return 0
```

Comment: solution found, was an "intruder" in /etc/bash_completion.d/virsh_bash_completion, thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found.
I think libvirt read completion from

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/vsh
```

But read from an "intruder" old file in `/etc/bash_completion.d/virsh_bash_completion`

I solved copy this file into /etc/bash_completion.d/virsh_bash_completion

```
sudo cp  /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/vsh /etc/bash_completion.d/virsh_bash_completion
```

Now works all.